# How is an mx:Canvas measured when inside a renderer in Flex 3?

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I'm having a sizing issue with a canvases located inside an HBox. It seems "_graphic", "_border" and "_fill" canvases (in com.example.ThingRenderer.mxml) do not get measured at the same time as all the other measurements inside the renderer. However, this problem is only observed on the first pass-through. Refer to the images for a visual... 1st image shows the state of the app after it finished loading. 2nd image represents what the screen looks like after the `Populate` button is clicked. 3rd image shows what happens when the stepper is incremented. The question is how come the drawing in the 3rd image doesn't get rendered once the data is populated into the table?

RendererTest.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    layout="absolute"
    creationComplete="handleCreationComplete(event)"
>
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import com.example.Thing;

            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.events.NumericStepperEvent;

            private const _thingProvider:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            private var _thing1:Thing;

            protected function handleCreationComplete(event:FlexEvent):void {
                _thing1 = new Thing("thingy", 0xff0000, 0.3);
                _stepper.value = _thing1.ratio;
            }

            protected function handlePopulateClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
                _thingProvider.addItem(_thing1);
            }

            protected function handleStepperChange(event:NumericStepperEvent):void {
                _thing1.ratio = event.value;
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:VBox>
        <mx:Button label="Populate" click="handlePopulateClick(event)" />
        <mx:NumericStepper id="_stepper" minimum="0" maximum="1" stepSize="0.01" change="handleStepperChange(event)" />
        <mx:AdvancedDataGrid dataProvider="{_thingProvider}" variableRowHeight="true" width="100%" height="100%">
            <mx:columns>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Name" dataField="name" />
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn headerText="Display"
                    width="150" sortable="false"
                    itemRenderer="com.example.ThingRenderer"
                />
            </mx:columns>
        </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:Application>
```

com.exampleThingRenderer.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"

    width="100%"
    horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off"
>
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.binding.utils.ChangeWatcher;

            private var _thing:Thing;
            private var _ratioWatcher:ChangeWatcher;

            private var _doClearContent:Boolean;
            private var _doDrawBorder:Boolean;
            private var _doUpdateFill:Boolean;

            override public function set data(value:Object):void {
                if(value && value is Thing) {
                    _thing = Thing(value);
                    if(_ratioWatcher) {
                        _ratioWatcher.unwatch();
                    }
                    _ratioWatcher = ChangeWatcher.watch(_thing, "ratio", handleRatioChanged);

                    _doClearContent = false;
                    _doDrawBorder = true;
                    _doUpdateFill = true;
                    _graphic.invalidateSize();
                    _border.invalidateSize();
                }
                else {
                    _doClearContent = true;
                    _doDrawBorder = false;
                    _doUpdateFill = false;
                }
                super.data = value;
            }

            private function handleRatioChanged(event:Event):void {
                _doUpdateFill = true;
                invalidateDisplayList();
            }

            override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
                if(_doClearContent) {
                    _container.visible = false;
                    _container.includeInLayout = false;
                    _doClearContent = false;
                }

                super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

                if(_doDrawBorder) {
                    trace("_thingContainer.width="+_container.width, "_thingGraphic.width="+_graphic.width, "_thingBorder.width="+_border.width);
                    _border.graphics.clear();
                    _border.graphics.moveTo(0, 0);
                    _border.graphics.lineStyle(1, _thing.color);
                    _border.graphics.lineTo(_border.width, 0);
                    _border.graphics.lineTo(_border.width, _border.height);
                    _border.graphics.lineTo(0, _border.height);
                    _border.graphics.lineTo(0, 0);

                    _doDrawBorder = false;
                }

                if(_doUpdateFill) {
                    _percentage.text = Math.round(_thing.ratio * 100.0) + "%";
                    _fill.graphics.clear();
                    _fill.graphics.beginFill(_thing.color);
                    _fill.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, _fill.width * _thing.ratio, _fill.height);

                    _doUpdateFill = false;
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </mx:Script>

    <mx:HBox id="_container" width="100%" paddingLeft="5" paddingTop="5" paddingRight="5" paddingBottom="5">
        <mx:Label id="_percentage" width="45" />
        <mx:Canvas id="_graphic" width="100%" height="15">
            <mx:Canvas id="_border" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
            <mx:Canvas id="_fill" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" />
        </mx:Canvas>
    </mx:HBox>
</mx:Canvas>
```

com.example.Thing.as

```
package com.example {
    public class Thing {
        [Bindable] public var name:String;
        [Bindable] public var color:uint;
        [Bindable] public var ratio:Number;

        public function Thing(name:String, color:uint, ratio:Number) {
            this.name = name;
            this.color = color;
            this.ratio = ratio;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Initial look when app has finished loading]

[image: After Populate button is clicked]

[image: After stepper is incremented from 0.30 to 0.40]

Comment: I played with it for about 30 minutes and got frustrated. I think _fill.width and __border.width coming back as 0. I don't know why it would do that though.

Comment: Because List components (and subclasses) set explicitWidth, not width (for some reason).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All this happens because you can't use width and height properties in updateDisplayList, they are not updated yet. Make separate component (e.g. ThingProgressBar) and put drawing logick inside it, that will solve everything:

```
package
{
import mx.core.UIComponent;

public class ThingProgressBar extends UIComponent
{
    private var _ratio:Number;
    public function get ratio():Number
    {
        return _ratio;
    }
    public function set ratio(value:Number):void
    {
        _ratio = value;
        invalidateDisplayList();
    }

    override protected function updateDisplayList(
                     unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void
    {
        super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
        graphics.clear();
        if (unscaledWidth > 0 && unscaledHeight > 0)
        {
            graphics.lineStyle(1, 0xFF0000);
            graphics.drawRect(0, 0, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);

            graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
            graphics.drawRect(0, 0, unscaledWidth * ratio, unscaledHeight);
            graphics.endFill();
        }
    }
}
}
```

So your renderer might look like this:

```
<mx:HBox
xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off" xmlns:local="*"
>
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        [Bindable] private var _thing:Thing;

        override public function set data(value:Object):void
        {
            _thing = value as Thing;
            super.data = value;
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<mx:HBox width="100%"
             paddingLeft="5" paddingTop="5"
             paddingRight="5" paddingBottom="5">
    <mx:Label text="{_thing.name}" width="45" />
    <local:ThingProgressBar width="100%" height="15"
                                    ratio="{_thing.ratio}"/>
</mx:HBox>
</mx:HBox>
```

1. I removed watcher. Binding by watcher is considered a bad practice, use mxml binding or events instead.
2. I removed two Canvases with separated border and fill - they can be cobined together.
3. I used UIComponent instead of Canvas. Don't use containers unless you need layout, they are heavy.
4. I used HBox instead of Canvas in renderer because I like boxes more :) But you can't avoid using second container in renderer if you need custom styles since List overwrites renderer's stylesheet.

Comment: I can see how what you're saying is a legitimate solution, but how come the size of _container (the mx:HBox that wraps the mx:Canvas) is correct in the updateDisplayList function? It's confusing and misleading - some components get sized and some don't... Any idea why that is?

Comment: @Andrey, look inside BoxLayout or Canvas, they operate with two pairs of functions and properties during updating: getExplicitOrMeasuredWidth/Heights() and percentWidth/Height, not width/heights itself. When container lays out its children, it can't affect it's grandchildren, instead they are queued in LayoutManager to layout and will be updated later (even maybe in the next frame). So when you try to somehow check grandchild's size in updateDisplayList, it remains zero or previous value.

Comment: This all makes sense now. Thank you for a great answer!